# wordpress login frontend not allow upload file

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, authentication, backend

I have ultimate membership pro for wordpress installed and when i login with plugin frontend form i can't upload a file or image. When i create a new user, after register is redirect me to user edit page and i can update a file, after i logout and login again the problem is back. The user role permission is set to upload file, from ftp the upload folder is 755, I think the login form is the problem. 
Another thing is when i login from wp-login.php as a user, the upload file is working, but i need to do this from front-end. Is something about session ? what are the differences between the two login forms (frontend / backend) ?